# Does using albums to combine events keep the events intact?

Tags: macos, photos.app, slideshow

If I use albums in iPhoto to combine events for a slideshow will the album keep each event intact and in order rather than combining pictures by date or some other hierarchy?

Comment: Are you asking if the sort order of an album that consists of photos from multiple events will group by events first before sorting?

Answer (score 1):

**Albums don't affect the contents of an event in any way**, so your events will remain exactly how you left them.